# Ubuntu installation gets stuck (Failed to start Wait for udev to complete device initialization)

Tags: boot, 22.04, hp, udev, amd-processor

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my HP Envy 13-ag0700ng. I created a boot stick using Balena Etcher and Rufus, both options with the same results. You can find the console output in the attached images. I used Zorin (an Ubuntu-based distro) before and I am now trying to switch to Ubuntu because of different issues. One is that Zorin often did not boot because of the network resolution/sync jobs that also occur now :( (Fig.2). The new error can be seen in Fig.1 and is probably something I should resolve to install Ubuntu properly. It takes the system approximately 10 minutes to get to the first failed message.

udev error:

[image]

network jobs:

[image]

Comment: In my opinion more ram or another flavor.

Comment: I tried 22, 20, and 18 all with the same result. More ram is not an option at the moment but shouldn't 8 GB be enough? Thanks anyways though (:

Comment: Man it is OEM killer.  Forget my previous comment.  

Comment: I can't find useful information on that. How would I fix this issue you mentioned?

Comment: OOM killer (earlyoom)I mean. Sorry for confusing you. please have you tried to install with an usb Stick instead of an DVD?

Comment: I always used an usb stick, no dvd. Thats why the message with the "change cds" is confusing to me :D